# Change name-attributes in Tell-a-friend-form?

Tags: forms, tell-a-friend

When I use the tell-a-friend-form the form is autogenerated by the tag

```
{exp:email:tell_a_friend ...}
```

Now the name of the sender has to be "from", the name of the recipient has to be "to". Simplified example for the form generated:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.xyz.com">
<input type="email" name="from">
...
</form>
```

Now it's important for me to change the names, because the Bootstrap-Validator astonishingly seems not to accept the same element-name twice on one page.

Is this possible or does anybody know a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the Tell A Friend form, no - these values are hard-coded, so you must submit an `input` with `name="to"`.

I suppose you could use a different `name`, then use some javascript on form submission that clones that value into a new input named `to`.

Note that although you can have form inputs with the same `name` attribute across different forms in the same document, make sure they have different `id` attributes.

Comment: Thanks Derek, for your explanation. I suspected this. I hope EllisLab will rebuild the form-handling in a next bigger version update.